# Having trouble identifying a kanji character in a comic strip

Tags: translation, kanji, kana, writing-identification

I'm "reading" a cute comic about a cat that has por luck, at the top of each strip is the title of the comic, but I can't identify this character:

[image]

The closest I can find is 生 (life), which might make sense in context, but is not all that close visually.

For context, this is the entire comic: [image]

Comment: That's what the cat keeps in his hands.

Comment: what is the title of this comic? sound interesting

Comment: Not sure of the series title, but the artist (qrais) posts them to their twitter: https://twitter.com/qrais_usagi    They also have a few other characters, like a wolf that looks mean, but is very kind, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's 缶{かん}, which means 'can', like the can the poor cat is trying to open.

Comment: Hahaha, that makes total sense! Thank you so much! I'll mark you correct as soon as I can